# doesn't update d3.js elements in .each function

Tags: javascript, d3.js, each

My code works and it shows me the elements for my data, but d3 doesn't update the text of my SVG Element after changing my data and running the same code again. I have to refresh the whole site for it to change.

```
var blackbox= d3.select("#content")
                            .selectAll(".silencer")
                            .data([0]);

                blackbox.enter()
                    .append("div")
                    .attr("class", "silencer")
                    .attr("id", "silencer");

                    blackbox.exit().remove();

                    var box = blackbox.selectAll(".ursa")
                    .data(fraung);

                    box.enter()
                    .append("div")
                    .attr("class", "ursa")                      
                    .each(function(d) {

                        d3.select(this)
                        .append("svg")                  
                        .attr("class", "invoker")                           
                        .each(function(d) {


                            d3.select(this).append("svg:image")
                                .attr("xlink:href", "images/qwer.png")
                                .attr("x", "0")
                                .attr("y", "0")
                                .attr("width", "100")
                                .attr("height", "100")
                                .append("title")
                                .text(function(d) {return (d.name)});   

                        });

                        d3.select(this).append("div")
                        .attr("class", "chen")              
                        .each(function(d) {


                            d3.select(this).append("table")
                            .attr("class", "tab")
                            .each(function(d) {
                                d3.select(this).append("tbody")
                                .each(function(d) {

                                    d3.select(this).append("tr")
                                    .text(function(d) {return("Name: ")})
                                    .attr("class", "key")
                                    .each(function(d) {
                                        d3.select(this).append("td")
                                        .text(function(d) {return (d.name)});
                                    });

                                }); 
                            });
                        }); 
                }); 

                box.exit().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your SVG element isn't being cleared before you load the second data set and so the second data set is being drawn behind the first. If the only thing that is changing is the text, it would look like nothing is happening at all. A browser refresh would clear any dynamically drawn content. Before you invoke "blackbox", you can do something like this to clear everything in the "#content" element, which I'm assuming is your SVG container.

```
if(!d3.select("#content").empty()) d3.select("#content").remove();
```

This will remove the SVG container entirely. So you'll have to create it again before you can load in new data. Alternatively if you just want to remove the child elements from the SVG container, you could do this:

```
if(!d3.select("#content").selectAll("*").empty()) d3.select("#content").selectAll("*").remove();
```

Comment: that would work probably, but I don't want to delete and create them again and again. There must be another way.

Comment: If you run the same code again, it will execute all of it, not just the part that controls the text elements, which I'm guessing is what's happening right now, hence the problem you describe. If you only want to change the text, you could check to see if content exists already, then select the preexisting text and change it rather than running all of the code block you posted.